# Unnecessary strip in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When compiling on mobile, an empty line appears that is not in the code. Everything is fine in the studio in the designer, but on the phone everything is different. Where could the error be?

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Row="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Column="0">
            <SearchBar  x:Name="SearchNickname" 
                        BackgroundColor="{Binding BackColor}"
                        CancelButtonColor="{Binding TextColor}" 
                        PlaceholderColor="{Binding TextColor}"
                        TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Placeholder="Введите свой ник"           
                        SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCmd}" 
                        Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceEventName=TextChanged}" 
                        MaxLength="100"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Column="1" BackgroundColor="{Binding BackColor}">
            <Button ImageSource="https://assets.laut.fm/f69a3423e545055c32430e0a77ebe148?t=_120x120" 
                    BackgroundColor="{Binding BackColor}"
                    Command="{Binding SettingsCmd}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Where does this strip come from? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6OBK.png)

Image in the designer studio [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38yoh.png)

Comment: what type of device are you testing on?

Comment: What is the root parent of your xaml? ContentPage? Shell..? probably it's the appbar/navigation bar.

Comment: set the navigation bar to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That strip along the top is the Header/Navigation Bar, which you get by default in Xamarin Forms Pages.  You can modify it or suppress it.